# When rendering iframes with <HTML />, Android crashes while navigating back to stack screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

When enabling screens in `react-native-screens`, and having a screen which renders an `<HTML />` component passed with an `iframe` HTML element, the app crashes while pressing the back button to return to the home screen. [Full reproduction here](https://github.com/drb1/DemoForVideoCrashHtml).

### Environment

- React Native: 0.61.5
- react-native-render-html: 4.2.2
- react-native-webview: 10.3.2
- react-native-screens: 2.8.0
- react-native-render-html-table-bridge: 0.6.1

### Crash log

```
07-29 17:41:49.173  6901  6901 F crashpad: dlopen: dlopen failed: library "libandroidicu.so" not found: needed by /system/lib/libharfbuzz_ng.so in namespace (default)
--------- beginning of crash
07-29 17:41:49.176  6410  6441 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1c in tid 6441 (RenderThread), pid 6410 (com.newmednav)
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:11/RPB2.200611.009/6625208:userdebug/dev-keys'
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2020-07-29 17:41:49+0545
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : pid: 6410, tid: 6441, name: RenderThread  >>> com.newmednav <<<
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : uid: 10152
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1c
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
07-29 17:41:49.340  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :     eax efbc2cb0  ebx eed5c69c  ecx eed52a80  edx 00000000
07-29 17:41:49.341  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :     edi d139ae90  esi 00000000
07-29 17:41:49.341  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :     ebp c086ed48  esp c086eb50  eip ee698c1c
07-29 17:41:49.425  6904  6904 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
07-29 17:41:49.425  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 00247c1c  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::GLFunctorDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+1548) (BuildId: 434a9b68672e1dd2b15599730362463d)
07-29 17:41:49.425  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00303a57  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+87) (BuildId: 434a9b68672e1dd2b15599730362463d)
07-29 17:41:49.425  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 002f4606  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkBaseDevice::drawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*, SkCanvas*)+38) (BuildId: 434a9b68672e1dd2b15599730362463d)
07-29 17:41:49.425  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00659291  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkGpuDevice::drawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*, SkCanvas*)+353) (BuildId: 434a9b68672e1dd2b15599730362463d)
07-29 17:41:49.425  6904  6904 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 002d9dc0  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::onDrawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*)+48) (BuildId: 434a9b68672e1dd2b15599730362463d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The updated solution for this is **androidLayerType="software"**, since **androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled** is now deprecated.

ex:-

```
<AutoHeightWebView
   androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled // update here androidLayerType="software"
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 10):

This was caused by an incompatibility between `react-native-webview` and `react-native-screens`, which you must depend on if you are using `@react-navigation/*` packages.

**EDIT**: there seems to have been a regression since. [It's being tracked here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9755).

### Fixed in `react-native-screens@2.12.0`

See CHANGELOG in https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/releases/tag/2.12.0

### If you can't upgrade react-native-screens

There are 3 workarounds:

#### WebView opacity

```js
const tagsStyles = {
    iframe: {
        opacity: 0.99
    },
    // If you are using @native-html/table-plugin
    table: {
        opacity: 0.99
    }
}
```

And use this prop when rendering:

```js
return <HTML tagsStyles={tagsStyles} ... />
```

#### Disabling hardware acceleration

In `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<activity
  android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
/>
```

#### Disabling native screens

From your `App.js` file:

```js
// import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens';

// enableScreens();
```

Comment: I'm using `react-native-screens 2.18.1`  and the error is persisted on android. have to set `animationEnabled=false` to workaround

Answer (score 6):

One more fix is to disable animation for react-navigation in navigationOptions.

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
  animationEnabled: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to add `androidLayerType: 'software'` in `webViewProps`  inside `htmlProps` which pass to render HTML table as mentioned below.

```
const webViewProps = {
    androidLayerType: 'software',
  }

  const htmlProps = {
    WebView,
    renderers: {
      table: TableRenderer,
    },
    renderersProps: {
      table: {
        cssRules,
        webViewProps,
        computeContainerHeight() {
          return null
        },
      },
    },
    customHTMLElementModels: {
      table: tableModel,
    },
  }
```

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6960#issuecomment-587418809

Comment: Helped me solve a problem that had been bothering me for a long time.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was triggered by social media iframes.
Applying `style = {{ opacity: 0.99 }}` was the only thing that worked for me:

```
 <WebView
    useWebKit={true}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    source={{ html: html }}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    bounces={false}
    overScrollMode={'never'}
    pagingEnabled={true}
    style={{ opacity: 0.99 }} //<---------
 />
```

Source: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/811

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the navigation animation for the screen worked for me. I just added the `animation: 'none',` screen option for the navigator, as shown below.

```js
const StackNavigator = props => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator  
      screenOptions={{
        animation: 'none', // <-- Add this.
      }}
    >
      // ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

***P.S.:** I also tried other options like*

1. *Setting the `opacity` of the `WebView` to `0.99`.*
2. *Setting the `renderToHardwareTextureAndroid={true}` for the parent `View` of the `WebView`.*
3. *Setting the `androidLayerType` property of the `WebView` to `"software"`.*
4. *Disabling hardware acceleration in *android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*'s `<activity>` by setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`.*

***1 and 2** were not useful and **3 and 4** while useful, also tended to cause only the audio to play and displayed a blank black screen.*

*Thus I found setting the `animation: 'none',` screen option for the navigator to be most useful.*
*This is the iFrame I used*

```html
<iframe 
  width="853" 
  height="480" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jbnUQ-o381k" 
  title="WAI WAI QUICK PYRO COMEDY CLUB WITH CHAMPIONS | EPI 52 | Bijay Baral, Bhola Raj Sapkota" 
  frameborder="0" 
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" 
  allowfullscreen
></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem for a very long time. It seems the problem is when the iframe gets rendered while the animation from the stack.navigation is still in progress.
For me the simplest solution was to block the iframe from rendering till the animation of the navigation has finished. The stack.navigator has a event for this.(transitionEnd).
To achieve this you can simply do some thing like this:

```
const [finishedTransition, setFinishedTransition] = setState(false)
React.useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('transitionEnd', (e) => {
    setFinishedTransition(true)
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
return(
  <>
      {finishedTransition ? <Html with iframe/> : null}
  </>
)
```